# Will you still get the weekly chest reward if you do not complete a mythic+ within the timer?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

If you complete a mythic+ instance but do not complete it in the timer, do you still get the weekly chest reward for that mythic+ keystone level?

For example, if i have a +7 key and we complete it, but we did not complete within the timer. Do we still get a weekly chest with the value of a +7 keystone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

The loot of the weekly chest is based on the highest instance you *finished*, it does not matter wether or not it was inside the time limit (Source: I have tried it — multiple times in fact).

Blizzards preview is worded slightly misleading in that way.

> After completing any Mythic Keystone dungeon within the time limit (whether using your own Keystone or someone else’s), a reward chest will be available in your Class Hall the following week. That chest contains a guaranteed piece of gear with a power level reflecting the highest Mythic level you completed during the prior week, up to a maximum of item level 880 for a successful Mythic Level 10 clear.

Source: https://worldofwarcraft.com/en-us/news/20271497/preview-mythic-keystones

I am not sure if you get a chest if the *only* instance you ran that week was not in the time limit. but the above suggests that you need to complete *any* (even only a M+2) instance within the time limit for the chest to appear. But the item level is definitely based on the highest instance you finished, however long it took.

Comment: Confirmed. As of 7.1.5. This works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do.

We did a +10 CoS and didn´t make it in time (pesky imps!) and i still got a 
mythic 10 item from my chest the following week.

Answer (score 0):

Blizzard says you need to complete it within the time limit in order to get access to the class hall chest. ([Source](https://worldofwarcraft.com/en-us/news/20271497/preview-mythic-keystones))

However, as it now is you only need to complete the dungeon in order to get the chest for that level. Not sure, if it's intended or a bug, but you'll get that level 7 chest.